# Copper to Silver, Gold conversion for roll20

Tags: javascript, html

Im new to this so... I have 4 input type = "numbers” fields that are Copper, Silver, Gold, and Platinum. When the players adds a number to any of the number boxes and clicks “add” the value needs to go to thats corresponding total and the number box needs to revert back to zero. When the total value is over 1000 it needs to -1000 from that total and add 1 to the next total field and so forth. For ex: player enters 105500 coppers then clicks “add” button it needs to update all the totals: copper=500 + current value, silver=5  + current value, gold=1  + current value, and plat=0  + current value. I also need it to be able to subtract and update all totals. I have added a solution i found and I believe it will work but im not sure how to make it work with the current fields. Or if there is a better way to accomplish this task im all ears

Below is what I started.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class = "sheet-currency">
<label> Copper </label>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_copper"></input>
    <span name = "coppertotal">0</span>
        </div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = “addMoney”></input>
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “addMoney” ></input>
<br></br>
<div>
<label> Silver </label>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_silver"></input>
        <span name = "silvertotal">0</span>
        </div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = “addMoney” ></input>
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “addMoney” ></input>
<br></br>
 <div>
<label> Gold </label>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_gold"></input>
        <span name = "goldtotal">0</span>
        </div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = “addMoney” ></input>
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “addMoney” ></input>
<br></br>
 <div>
<label> Plat <label>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_plat"></input>
        <span name = "plattotal">0</span>
        </div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = “addMoney” ></input>
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “addMoney” ></input>
<br></br>


<script>

var copper = 0;
var silver = 0;
var gold = 0;
var plat = 0;

function addMoney(type, amount){
    if(type=='copper'){
        copper += amount;
        while(copper >= 1000){
            copper -= 1000;
            silver++;
        }
        while(silver >= 1000){
            silver -= 1000;
            gold++;
        }
    } else if(type=='silver'){
        silver += amount;
        while(silver >= 1000){
            silver -= 1000;
            gold++;
        }
    } else if(type=='gold'){
        gold += amount;
        while(gold >= 1000){
            gold -= 1000;
            plat++;
        }
    } else if(type=='plat'){
        plat += amount;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few changes to you script & html gives you results.
1. remove all `</input>` there is no such tag
2. define parameters for `addMoney` function
3. use JavaScript's getElementById method to get value of textbox and set text inside span.
4. you need to define `subMoney` similarly with substraction logic,it's you playground now ;)

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class = "sheet-currency">
    <lable> Copper </lable>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_copper" id="txtCopper">
    <span id = "coppertotal">0</span>
</div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = 'addMoney("copper", "txtCopper")'>
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “subMoney” >
<br>
<br>

<div>
<label> Silver </label>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_silver" id="txtSilver">
    <span id = "silvertotal">0</span>
</div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = 'addMoney("silver","txtSilver")' >
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “subMoney” >
<br>
<br>

<div>
<label> Gold </label>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_gold" id="txtGold">
    <span id = "goldtotal">0</span>
</div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = 'addMoney("gold","txtGold")' >
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “subMoney” >
<br>
<br>

<div>
 <label> Plat </label>
    <input type = "numbers" name = "attr_plat" id="txtPlat">
    <span id = "plattotal">0</span>
</div>
<input type = "button" value = "Add" onclick = 'addMoney("plat","txtPlat")' >
<input type = "button" value = "Sub" onclick = “subMoney” >
<br>
<br>


<script>

var copper = 0;
var silver = 0;
var gold = 0;
var plat = 0;

function addMoney(type, amountTextBox){

var amount = Number(document.getElementById(amountTextBox).value);
 if(isNaN(amount))
  {  
   return;
  }
    
  if(type=='copper'){
    copper += amount;
    while(copper >= 1000){
     copper -= 1000;
      silver++;
    }
    while(silver >= 1000){
     silver -= 1000;
      gold++;
    }
  } 
  else if(type=='silver'){
      silver += amount;
      while(silver >= 1000){
          silver -= 1000;
          gold++;
      }
  } 
  else if(type=='gold'){
      gold += amount;
      while(gold >= 1000){
          gold -= 1000;
          plat++;
      }
  } 
  else if(type=='plat'){
      plat += amount;
  } 
  else {
      return false;
  }
    
  document.getElementById("coppertotal").textContent = copper;
  document.getElementById("silvertotal").textContent = silver;
  document.getElementById("goldtotal").textContent = gold;
  document.getElementById("plattotal").textContent = plat;    
   
  document.getElementById(amountTextBox).value = 0;
  return true;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to apply this logic to the subtraction portion.